# Filling and creating table with input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

My inputs:

```
<input id="id_name" name="name"/>
<input id="id_age" name="age"/>
<button id="add_btn"></button>
```

After every click on button `add_btn` I need append my table(`<tr>`) with form input value. At the start,  the table is empty. Only `<tbody>`.

```
<table class="mytab">
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> HERE_VALUE_FROM_NAME_FIELD</td>
        <td>HERE_VALUE_FROM_AGE_FIELD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> HERE_NEXT_VALUE_FROM_NAME_FIELD</td>
        <td>HERE_NEXT_VALUE_FROM_AGE_FIELD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Onclick function:

```
$("#myform").on('click', "#add_btn", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //fill table
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

**HTML**

```
<input id="id_name" name="name"/>
<input id="id_age" name="age"/>
<button id="add_btn">click</button>

<table border="1" class="mytab"></table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#add_btn").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#id_name').val(), 
        age = $('#id_age').val();

    $('<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+age+'</td></tr>').appendTo( $('.mytab') );
});
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/dfg2R/

**Helpful link:**
[appendTo()](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: Why no `var` before `age`? Edit: Nevermind, I didn't notice the comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the insertRow and insertCell on the returned row.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfg2R/2/

[insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell)

[insertRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow)

Here is an example:

```
$("#myform").on('click', "#add_btn", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var table = $("table.mytab")[0]
        var newRow = table.insertRow(0);
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
        newCell.innerText = $("#id_name").val();
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
        newCell.innerText = $("#id_age").val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A little search about jQuery DOM will give you the answer. see [jQuery.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$( '#table_id' ).append(
    $('<tr />').append(
        $('<td/>').text($('#id_name').value())
    ).append(
        $('<td/>').text($('#id_age').value())
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery you could use [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$(".myTab tbody").append("<tr><td>" + valueName+ "</td><td> + valueAge + </td></tr>");
```